# Typescript function that takes union of objects with Date properties, and return the same objects with Dates converted to strings

Tags: typescript

See the following code:

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gQgKQKIGEAqB9AkgOSgXigG8AoKcqAYwCcIBDYCAEwC4oARBiAGjIoBs6AZ2ABZAPZMAlgDMpzNp0a8KUANoBrCCDYjqUgHYBzALpsArgY0HxAdwMkAviRKhIsRKkwBGAsT7kNPSMrFB6hkYqAsJikrLyoeHGUeTiAEYAVhCUwN4ACtTiYGwAROlZOfmFYCVOLm7Q8MjoGABMfqSqQVyJwPrJAVCCIhLScgphfREpUOXZwK0FRaVzOYvVtc6u4I2e6ADKGDAAqmh+TV4YvgA+Hs2YrS4yljlS4gZU7wBuENTAShA0OJ9lNjAAeM4QAAejAMTCEd0uuAAfAAKcpsNAASjYFwOR1O-lUtGA5moBlRnVUFAAdHTyjMurQemxyjTuiEacBxFh9jAQf0jKisYzoiM4uNQmzhrExgkuTy+QKIsLBo4sQBuOokSjvESzTLzABihQAtuw0h1HFrdQZ9bQhOZ+MA-Lafn8AUDlcZ0YacibxObLcJES1cJqgA)

There is a `convertDateToString` function that should take a object of type `OBJECT_IN`, which have two `Date` properties and some more `[key: string]: unknown` properties.

It should return `OBJECT_1 | OBJECT_2`. Because when I get those types from my database, the dates come back as `Date` and I need to convert them to `string` before saving to state.

```
type OBJECT_IN = {
    created: Date,
    lastModified: Date,
    [key: string]: unknown
}

type OBJECT_1 = {
    created: string,
    lastModified: string,
    object1Prop: "object1Prop"
}

type OBJECT_2 = {
    created: string,
    lastModified: string,
    object2Prop: "object2Prop"
}

type OBJECTS_OUT = OBJECT_1 | OBJECT_2

function convertDateToString<T extends OBJECT_IN>(obj: T): OBJECTS_OUT {
    return({
        ...obj,
        created: obj.created.toISOString(),
        lastModified: obj.lastModified.toISOString()
    });
}
```

Currently, Typescript is complaining about that return type.

[image]

I know I can "brute force" the return type using type assertions like the on in the following code, but I'd rather work with the correct types in and out.

```
return({
  ...obj,
  created: obj.created.toISOString(),
  lastModified: obj.lastModified.toISOString()
}) as unknown as OBJECTS_OUT;
```

How can I fix this error and make Typescript that the `return` should be `OBJECT_1 | OBJECT_2` ?

---

UPDATE:

This is what I'm currently trying.

I've made both `OBJECT_1 and 2` as generics, so I can let Typescript know that they will be entering with the dates as `Date` and should come out with the dates as `string`

```
type OBJECTS_IN = OBJECT_1<Date> | OBJECT_2<Date>
```

But I'm still getting error:

[image]

See full code: [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgggFQKIGUoF4oGdgCcCWAdgOZQA+sAhsBAFC2iRQDyAQgFJIDCCA+gIwAeBFAgAPGoQAmWWIlQZseIsQB8igN60oOqAGNcEahCkAuKAgA023QBtKOALIB7KfgBm+E+as2dzgCMAKwg9YH4ABVxnMHMAIkCQsMjosDjaAF96Rmg2Th5eACZhUQkIaVl4ZDRMHAISdUwtXX1DYzMLaxb7J1cPLw7fFsTQ4EKomPiRsPHU9KyGcFyObgQUXgBJADlFPNWBQRhjdQo9guKjmlVFpjO13mYAVRFMO4FyFhXz+ncAV0IwvhnIR9MCAG4QXDAS4QBDOFDKEglcSSGSffL3baqAAUiR8AEpzHd1k8RM1dIZgL9cIRseSWjoAHTMxJdBk6AxGGgdRKMzntRnAZwbFDMBH1YjY-Fs9k9YAuNyebxQXlyhX9EyC4Wi8UqKV+KAZfEAbky9D0wJwKuCowAYtEALYwAKaDKmi2EK2GLC-WzARQeiFQmFw3UkXE2sL25xOl0OdGrdbbE1AA)

```
type DATES = string | Date

type OBJECT_1<T extends DATES = string> = {
    created: T,
    lastModified: T,
    object1Prop: "object1Prop"
}

type OBJECT_2<T extends DATES = string> = {
    created: T,
    lastModified: T,
    object2Prop: "object2Prop"
}

type OBJECTS_IN = OBJECT_1<Date> | OBJECT_2<Date>
type OBJECTS_OUT = OBJECT_1 | OBJECT_2

function convertDateToString<T extends OBJECTS_IN>(obj: T): OBJECTS_OUT {
    return({
        ...obj,
        created: obj.created.toISOString(),
        lastModified: obj.lastModified.toISOString()
    });
}

const objectFromDb = {};
const result = convertDateToString(objectFromDb as OBJECTS_IN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work:

The function doesn't need to extend the `OBJECTS_IN` like I was trying to do, but it should rather take `obj: OBJECTS_IN` directly.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-WzARReiFQmFw9XI6bAS3OG0BPVAA)

```
type DATES = string | Date

type OBJECT_1<T extends DATES = string> = {
    created: T,
    lastModified: T,
    object1Prop: "object1Prop"
}

type OBJECT_2<T extends DATES = string> = {
    created: T,
    lastModified: T,
    object2Prop: "object2Prop"
}

type OBJECTS_IN = OBJECT_1<Date> | OBJECT_2<Date>
type OBJECTS_OUT = OBJECT_1 | OBJECT_2

function convertDateToString(obj: OBJECTS_IN): OBJECTS_OUT {
    return({
        ...obj,
        created: obj.created.toISOString(),
        lastModified: obj.lastModified.toISOString()
    });
}

const objectFromDb = {} as OBJECT_1<Date>;
const result = convertDateToString(objectFromDb);
```